# How can I get post to be created on rails after setting up users with devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I am trying to build a basic User/Post app on Ruby on Rails and everything was working smoothly, but then I added the devise gem to create the login/sign up for me and now I am not able to create a post. Once the user signs in they are redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts. There they can click "add new plant" (its posts about plants) and it takes them to the http://localhost:3000/posts/new page. Here the form is up and running, the user can fill in the title and description and hit the create post button, but then it just stays on this page and nothing happens. The post doesnt even get saved. If anyone could please give me some insight on how I can attempt to fix this, I would really appreciate it! The posts were being created normally before I added the users table with devise.

```
Started POST "/posts" for ::1 at 2020-07-26 12:24:01 -0400
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Fm7HPgNsIJkKYzgOm/ApVCZfZJJuVQOLMP7eZvz1zFLok1QZdPxGC3f0p1Z1sRdUofCMlL5RU8wXwv31FIkj0w==", "post"=>{"title"=>"Lavender ", "description"=>"testing hello "}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (Duration: 13.2ms | Allocations: 5423)
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 13.6ms | Allocations: 5487)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 29.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 11827)
```

that is the what shows up when I hit the create post button. Here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_07_26_023022) do

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Here is my posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
    end

    def new 
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create 
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        if @post.save
            redirect_to @post 
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit 
    end

    def update 
        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post
        else 
            rend 'new'
        end

    end

    def destroy 
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to posts_path
    end

    private 
        def find_post
            @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        end

        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :user_id)
        end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help You...:

In controller:

```
  def create 
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user # here You setting the user

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post 
    else
      puts @post.errors # this should print errors to the console  
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

In models

```
module User
  has_many :posts

  ...
end


module Post
  belongs_to :user

  ...
end
```

Comment: This seemed to work!!! Thank you so much. I just learned more about Devise and didn't know I had to set the user as current_user. I think that did the trick. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some validation is failing for the Post. I'll advise to do something like this in your controller:

```
    def create 
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
        if @post.save!
            redirect_to @post 
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

`save!` will immediately fail if the issue is indeed in the validation and you'll be able to debug it further.

OR

I see in the logs that request is complete. It might be possible that posts are actually getting created? Did you check your Database?